# Outlook meeting requests and mail resending or repeating - Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007

I've had strange Exchange (or maybe Outlook) problems the last two days.

Someone sent a meeting notice to all employees two days ago (2009-06-23 16:48) for an event on Friday.  (This is a regularly scheduled Friday lunch, but it's not set up as a recurring meeting because the food comes from somewhere different every week, and the organizer needs a count and food orders from each attendee.  She puts the details (the menu choices) into the meeting request.)  **It was repeating at irregular intervals, between 15 and 20 times in 24 hours, to everyone.**

- I rebooted Exchange, though saw
  nothing unusual in any logs.  That
  didn't help.
- I had the user totally
  close (and that means
  killing the Outlook.exe process) and restart Outlook. No good.
- Finally, cancelling the meeting (at 14:59 on 2009-06-24) took care of it.

But wait. . . there's more.

Today, I received a meeting request from my manager three times.  It was not sent to the whole company like the one above, but I was on it, as was a small distribution group. He said he's pretty sure he DIDN'T send this request.  The request was dated yesterday (2009-06-24 12:05). He had to cancel it twice to stop it.

The meetings were scheduled using two different conference rooms as resources, so that's not a common thread either.

Quite honestly, I'm thinking it might be Outlook, and not Exchange, based on the fact that I see nothing unusual in any log files, and past experience with Outlook and repeating messages (albeit in a POP environment, not Exchange).

Anyone have any ideas?  If there's any additional info or data people think would be helpful, let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: If anyone finds a good fix for this I would appriciate it. I've had this happen three times my company and I have been able to stop the messages from spamming everyone by disconnecting the iPhone being used from the exchange server. The spamming stopped but I would like to prevent this from happening again in the future.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.slipstick.com/calendar/iphone_meetingbug.asp

probably has an iphone too . . .

Comment: Well, I tried duplicating the problem by setting up a test meeting with a distribution group of which I am a member, per the link above, but did not get repeats.  Most of our employees have company iPhones, so it seems like a reasonable avenue to pursue.  Next time it occurs, I'll investigate whether or not the circumstances in that blog exist here.

Answer (score 0):

This could be down to incorrectly setup delegates receiving meetings requests???

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue with one user with one appointment.  He has Outlook 2007, the server is Exchange 2003 running on Windows 2003 Standard 32-bit.  His appointment kept repeating (sending out response requests) every 20 minutes until we deleted the appointment.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound off base, but are you excluding the appropriate directories, files, and processes from your AV software on the Exchange server? I've seen AV software do some pretty strange things on Exchange if the Exchange directories, files, and processes weren't excluded.